# Ruby regex not working in Java

Tags: java, ruby, regex

I have this Ruby code:

```
line = "this is u.s.a. please come home. where are you"
res = line.split(/(.*?[.!?](?:["')\]}]|(?:<.*>))*[\s])/)
```

and it returns `["", "this is u.s.a. ", "", "please come home. ", "where are you"]`.

But when I tried same regex and same code in Java:

```
String line = "this is u.s.a. please come home. where are you";
String[] res = line.split("^(.*?[.!?]((?:([\"')\\]}])|(?:<.*>))*)[\\s])");
```

and it returns only two elements: `{ "" , "please come home. where are you"}`.

What’s wrong with my Java regex?

Comment: How did you get the second regex from the first one?

Comment: I just port the first regex into java as there is some difference in Regular Expression BTW Ruby and java. If you Feel its wrong(Second Regex) please do tell me...

Comment: I can't help but feel that both regular expressions are hopelessly overcomplicated for what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: Ya i Know this Regex is too complicated. Its Breaking sentences from a text as you can see.. it has "non capturing group" positive look ahead and a lot of stuff.. But First one that i have taken from gem code is Working fine you can Try it in console..All i need to do is to port this regex in java

Comment: @sumit if you're splitting sentences, why is /[\.\?!]\s{1,2}/ not sufficient?  Why do you need so many special characters?

Comment: @mcfinnigan if you are talking about (? ! .) i need these in my regex because most of the time sentence ends with these character like.- [ where are you(?) its mine(!) i live in England(.) ] and yes i am splitting sentences from given String...

Comment: @sumit So it’s intentional that your Ruby version reports empty Strings sporadically? And why are you matching against all these closing braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String line = "this is u.s.a. please come home. where are you";
String[] res = line.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s+");
```

gives `"this is u.s.a."` `"please come home."` `"where are you"`

Not the same a your Ruby version, but that version doesn’t appear sound to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holger works for me now. Don't know how it will go in Future.... Currently it fragmenting Sentence from Text...